# How many nodes are there on Tezos?

Tags: node

And which website is the best to get this data from?

Any screenshots of API pulled would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Baking Bad wrote [an article](https://baking-bad.org/blog/2020/07/30/inspecting-tezos-network-decentralization-200-public-nodes-1000-in-total/) on the number of nodes. This is a bit old but very relevant to your questions. The takeaway is that at that time there were approximately:

- 200 public nodes
- 400 bakers
- 1600 nodes

Answer (score 1):

You can't know the exact number of nodes since they can come/go and not every node connects to every other node. Nodes can also choose to be private and thus their info is not broadcasted to other nodes.

This is your best public list for nodes:

https://tzkt.io/network

Answer (score -1):

You probably mean active bakers instead of nodes. It is almost impossible to know the exact number of nodes in the network. Bakers are the ones participating in the consensus.

Currently, there are 402 active bakers in the network.

You can query the following RPC to get the active bakers:

> /chains/main/blocks/head/context/delegates?active

You can also get the information from [TzStats](https://tzstats.com/bakers) or [TzKt](https://tzkt.io/bakers/all).